# Is there sklearn library with parameter to set max and min, so .fit() is based on that max and min instead of the train set?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

My goal is to scale a percentage column to 0 and 1. PS: i am not sure if this is legal or not, should I do this or should I set the min and max based on the train set?

However, the `sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler` does not let you do that although I already set the feature_range parameter.

The code

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

X_train = [[60],
           [70]]

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))

scaler.fit(X=X_train)

scaler.transform([[100]])
```

My expectation is that `[[100]]` is scaled to `1`.

The actual output is that `[[100]]` scaled to `4`.

Current solution

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.base import _OneToOneFeatureMixin, TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator
import numpy as np

def isolate():
    X_train = [[60, 50],
               [70, 90]]
    
    class PercentageScaler(_OneToOneFeatureMixin, TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator):
        def __init__(self) -> None:
            super().__init__()
        
        def fit(self, X, y=None):
            return self
        
        def transform(self, X):
            return np.array(X) / 100

    percent_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
        ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median')),
        ('scaler', PercentageScaler())
    ])

    num_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
        ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median')),
        ('scaler', MinMaxScaler())
    ])

    transformer = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
        ('percent', percent_transformer, [0]),
        ('num', num_transformer, [1])
    ])

    transformer.fit(X=X_train)

    print(transformer.transform([[100, 60]]))

isolate()
```

Answer (score 0):

For model training, in order to have robust performance, we expect to see a similar distribution between train and test data (or even the real data that you will run inference later on). So I would let the Scaler to use the min and max based on the train set.

Of course, in reality, the values might go out of the range that trained model has seen but the difference shouldn't be too big. Otherwise, you won't be confident about the prediction anymore.

And MinMaxScaler do have an option to clip the scaled value to your expected range by setting clip=True in the parameter.

The code can be as follow:

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1), clip=True)
```

Reference: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler

P/s: I think your solution is good to go also. But just making sure that the distribution between train and test data is similar. It's the most important point to me.

Hope this help.